# use Jquery to insert div on my page to another part of my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am going to give a simple example of what I want to do.

I have this table. Static. I have five button and five corrisponding divs. When I click the button I want the table to be placed in the corrisponding div.

something like.

```
$("#button1").button().click($("#div1").append($("#mytable"));
```

and so on. Can this be done? How?

Also, Please tell me if there is a better way to do this, if I trying to re-invent the wheel or something like that...

WORKING:

The code I ended up using, based off of solutions:

```
$("#test").button().click(function() { $("#test2").append($("#table_EditInformation")); });
```

test is a button
test2 is a div
table_EditInforation is obviously a table

Comment: I should proly note that I don't want to put 5 copies of the table on the page, one in each div, and do hide/show when the button is clicked, eventhough I know that it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for a working example copy the html/js below into a "index.html" or any .html file and try it out.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function () {
         $("#div1").empty().append($("#mytable"));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="button1">the link or button to be pressed</a>
<div id="div1">
   <p>stuff should be put here</p>
</div>
<table id="mytable">
   <tr>
      <td>put my table in the div please! </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

the plain javascript code is following:

```
    $("#button1").click(function () {
     $("#div1").append($("#mytable"));
   });
```

remember, the element with the id $("#mytable") must be in the same dom tree.

also you can use .empty() before .append() to empty out the content of #div

like this:

```
  $("#button1").click(function () {
     $("#div1").empty().append($("#mytable"));
   });
```

Check the documentation here [jquery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: +1, this can also be improved to find the parent DIV of the button thus save the need to hardcode the id but that's only a bonus. :)

Comment: So it looks like my main issue was i didnt say .html()

Comment: Nope, i'm just stupid. I didn't put the # in front of the table name... wow i'm an idiot. So, whats the difference between putting .html() and not putting it? I seem to get the same effect? Oh and thanks for the tip about empty() i need that too!

Comment: yes, you basically only got the element with the id "mytable" but you did not do anything with it. You want "mytable" and all elements within "mytable"

Comment: actually you are correct with just $("mytable")!!! $("mytable").html() will only get the including html tags and will not include the parent. thus it will not include the table tags. I have corrected it above.

Comment: Just to give anyone reading some more information, when you don't use .html() and you just say append(), the table is removed from it's old location and placed in the new one! (which works for me :))

Comment: I think the main issue is the .button() function. does it even exist in jquery? and you did not have a callback function for the click action ...

Comment: i'm sorry, .button() is not actually a part of JQuery, which is why you may not be familiar with it. It is a part of JQueryUI.

Comment: ok that was my next question, if you were using UI ;-)! Great if it is working for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#div1").append($("#mytable"));
  });
```

Should do it for you

Answer (score 1):

```
function appendTableTo(divId) {
  $('#mytable')
    .remove()             // take the table out of whatever div it's in
    .appendTo(divId);     // and place it into the right div
}

function addHandler(buttonId, divId) {
  $(buttonId).button().click(
    function(divId){
      return function(){
        appendTableTo($(divId));
      };
    }(divId)
  );
}

addHandler('#button1', '#div1');
addHandler('#button2', '#div2');
addHandler('#button3', '#div3');
addHandler('#button4', '#div4');
addHandler('#button5', '#div5');
```

This should do it. We have only one append function that places the table into the right div. Furthermore, we have a function that attaches this click handler to a button. And we call that five times.

The addHandler function uses a closure. That is necessary because we need to pass an argument to the appendTableTo function, and that is not possible otherwise.

Comment: I really like this solution. Mabye I could do something with classes so I don't have to repeat addHandler each time. have the buttons all have the same class="myclass" then add the handler to everythinge with .myclass ... that would be really good for my situation.

Comment: The diffculty with using a class is associating divs to buttons. You could also use a loop: for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) addHandler('#button'+i, '#div'+i);

Comment: unless you wraped the div and button in another div. <div><button></button><div></div></div> you could get the div by when the button is click saying .parent().children("div") or something of the sort.

Comment: add class="myTestDiv" to the outerdiv and class="myTableDiv" to the inner div. Then when the button is clicked do something like $(this).parents(".myTestDiv").chilren(".myTableDiv").append("#myTable") . I think that should work

Comment: Yes, that is a great idea. Then you really need just one call using a class.

Comment: yup just say every button with that class do the code I said above.